# For what $p$ and $q$ ($p,q \in N$): $pq \geq p+q$?

Tags: inequality

lets say i have the next equation:
$p,q \in N-\{0\}$, $p,q \ge 2 : pq = p+q$
i want to show that only for $p,q = 2$ both sides of the equation are equal.
any chance for help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$pq\ge p+q$$
$$pq-p-q\ge0$$
$$pq-p-q+1\ge1$$
$$p(q-1)-(q-1)\ge1$$
$$(p-1)(q-1)\ge1$$
If $p>2$ or $q>2$ then $(p-1)(q-1)>1$

Comment: @MichaelBurr: In problem say $p,q \ge 2$

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is:

$$pq=p+q \Rightarrow p(q-1)=q \Rightarrow p|q$$

$$pq=p+q \Rightarrow q(p-1)=p \Rightarrow q|p$$

and then $p=q$, once $p,q$ are natural numbers.

The equation becames:

$$p^2=2p \Rightarrow p=2 \Rightarrow p=q=2$$

Comment: why would you assume or conclude that $p = q$?

Comment: As you can see above $p|q$ and $q|p$ so $p=q$ once $p,q$ are natural numbers. Is that clear?

Comment: yeah, nice answer indeed.